# Automate whatsapp using python

Tags: python, android, pydroid

I'm trying to automate whatsapp using python in my android phone. I'm using pydroid 3 ide to do it.
From the terminal I installed pywhatkit

```
$ pip install pywhatkit
```

And i logged into whatsapp web from chrome browser.

Now I've write the script named **test.py** like this -

```
 import pywhatkit 
 pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("+9176xxxxxx18","hello","10,36")
```

(My number imstead of +9176xxxxxxxx18)

(I've set the time 2 minutes later from my time)
But whenever I run the script it throws an error in importing pywhatkit

Something like this -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pywhatkit/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pywhatkit.main import print_sleep_time, check_window, sendwhatmsg, sendwhatmsg_to_group, info, playonyt, search, close_tab, sendwhatmsg_instantly, sendwhats_image
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pywhatkit/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pyautogui as pg
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/aarch64-linux-android/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 675, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'DISPLAY'

[Program finished]
```

Image :- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALeIw.jpg)

I can't understand why I'm getting this error please help me.let me know if there any other way to send whatsapp messege using python on android? I also have a terminal termux on my android which runs on linux into bash [my desi terminal ]

Comment: It would appear that the environment variable `DISPLAY` isn't set on your phone.  Whether it needs to and what it should be I can't say, I don't do anything android.  But the `linux` tag is highly misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you are trying to run from mobile[android] device, this module requires PC browser. So it wont be able to run in your mobile. Try running test.py through your PC. *And you cant send whatsapp messege using python on android*.